# Iterate through values of dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, lambda

I have been trying to iterate through the values of my dictionary. The dictionary looks like this:

```
temperature = {
    'June': [25,25,26,27,25,25,24,27,28,28,31,32,33],
    'July': [34,34,36,39,39,38,39,37,39,41,41,39,37],
    'August': [37,37,36,37,35,35,34,37,38,34,32,33,31],
}
```

and I am trying to find the month with the max value. So far my code i up to this point:

```
def minEl(dictionary):
    for key in dictionary:
        for i in key:
            for o in i:
                l = min(((k,v[o]) for k,v in temperature.items()),key=lambda x:x[o])
                return l
```

But the error message shows that I can't use a letter as list indices.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I tried to make it into a list of lists but it is not practical because I will not be able to automatically return the month and then I tried to use lambdas like this l = min(((k,v[1]) for k,v in temperature.items()), key=lambda x:x[1])

Comment: will this work? for key in dictionary:
        for i in key:
            for o in i:

Comment: `max(temperature.items(), key=lambda x: max(x[1]))[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to extract the max value for every month, and then use the max() function again by providing the resulting dictionary's values as the key to compare:

```
>>> max_per_month = {k:max(temperature[k]) for k in temperature}
>>> max_per_month
{'June': 33, 'July': 41, 'August': 38}
>>> max(max_per_month, key=max_per_month.get)
'July'
```

EDIT:
Actually, we can make it even more succint with a one-liner that's readable:

```
>>> t = {'June': [39, 40, 41], 'July': [39, 40], 'August': [40, 41]}
>>> max(t, key=lambda x: max(t[x]))
'June'
>>> t = {'June': [39, 40, 41], 'July': [39, 40], 'August': [40, 41, 42]}
>>> max(t, key=lambda x: max(t[x]))
'August'
>>> t = {'June': [39, 40, 41], 'July': [39, 40, 42], 'August': [40, 41, 42]}
>>> max(t, key=lambda x: max(t[x]))
'July'
```

We get month with the max by providing the key with the max of every month (`max(t[x])`).

Comment: I've not seen this `key` parameter for `max()` before, and nor do I understand why it is a function. Can you point me to any links to read up on this, please?

Comment: @butterflyknife, you can read Python's official documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max